# Magento 2.2.4 - incredibly slow only on remote machine. Problem already starts with php bin/magento

Tags: magento2, php

So lately after some updates on my life site I found out it got extremely slow. From < 1 sec response to more than 4 secons TTFB with varnish and over 30 seconds without. (Production mode)

I found out the problem starts already when using php bin/magento
Here is a comparison of a classic cli php -v call and php bin/magento

```
time php -v:   
real    0m0.170s 
user    0m0.056s
sys     0m0.068d

time php bin/magento: 
real    0m27.561s
user    0m26.364s
sys     0m1.000s
```

Can anyone help trace the root of this issue. I tried everything. Super frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this here in order it does not happen to anyone else.

After 7 days of hell debugging it was the most obvious thing ever. Caches were all disabled on my live production environment.

I don't know how this happened. I never disable it, but it finally got resolved.